# Obter múltiplos IDS, mas realizar operações diferentes em cada um deles

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma função que obtém multiplos ids de uma só vez, porém tenho que realizar operações ligeiramente diferentes em cada um deles, por causa disso acabo sendo obrigado a criar 3 variáveis para cada id diferente. A ideia é que se houver conteúdo html no id3, os ids 1 e 2 não devem ser exibidos, o que leva a outra repetição de `style.display='none'`. Tentei criar uma variável (`var s = s.style.display='none'`) para simplificar a aplicação, mas não sei como aplicar. Minha dúvida é se há um meio de reduzir a quantidade de `getElementById` de 3 para 1, bem como o `style.display='none'`., ou qualquer outra coisa que reduza o número de repetições. Agradeço desde já pela atenção.

```
function IDs(id1, id2, id3) {

var a = document.getElementById(id1);
var b = document.getElementById(id2);
var c = document.getElementById(id3);

var s = s.style.display='none'; // variável para aplicar estilo

if (a.innerHTML) {
c.style.display='none';
}

else {
a.style.display='none';
b.style.display='none';
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery facilita bastante para economizar código:
Você pode chamá-lo de qualquer ação do jquery, como um onclick, por exemplo:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('#id1').html()) {
        $('#id3').hide();
    } else {
        $('#id1').hide();
        $('#id2').hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

Porém, para fazer com javascript puro, daria para ecomonizar código da seguinte forma:

```
<script>
function myHide(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display='none';
}

if (document.getElementById('id1').innerHTML) {
    myHide('id3');
} else {
    myHide('id1');
    myHide('id2');
}
</script>
```

Espero ter auxiliado, abraço!

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda, porém, gostaria que a solução fosse em JavaScript puro, sem o uso de Jquery.

Comment: Eden, dei uma complementada na resposta, com o que consegui imaginar para ecomonizar código em javascript puro. Também gosto de "economizar dedos" e tentar deixar mais claro e legível. Boa iniciativa. Abraço

Comment: É possível definir `document.getElementById()`, `.innerHTML` e `.style.display='none'` em variáveis separadas, e depois uni-los, talvez tipo: `id.style`, ou `id+=style`, para que se torne `document.getElementById(id).style.display='none'`, e `id.inn`, ou `id+=inn` para que se torne `document.getElementById(id).innerHTML`?

Comment: Cada coisa no seu lugar. `getElementById()` é uma função e retorna um objeto, que por sua vez tem outros métodos que podem ser acionados posteriormente... `.innerHTML` é um parâmetro que contem uma string, retorna ela própria. Ambas podem ser atribuidas a outras variáveis. Já `.style.display='none', é uma atribuição, no máximo irá retornar true, indicando sucesso da operação. Não sei se respondi, mas considere usar jQuery, ajuda muito nessa trabalho de economizar e organizar o código. []s